# How to disable a RepositoryLookUpEdit in a different grid?

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I have two xtragrid in a form, both have the same objects as a datasource... my problem is:

If I select a value from a `RepositoryLookUpEdit` in the first grid, the second grid must disable the same `RepositoryLookUpEdit`, for example:

The object is a Product, which has an Id = 1, I select the storage of the product to Storage = "In stock", the second grid must disable the Storage column.

At this point I have been disable the repository, but it disables all the repositories in the column, and not the only want that I need. Also I disable the repository, but the grid get stuck in the first row and I can't select any othe row.

Comment: Can you show your code on how you are currently attempting to disable?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand all of what you have said, but you can try the following approaches:

1. To assign individual editor for rows subscribe to CustomRowCellEdit [event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomRowCellEdittopic).
2. To manipulate a data source of a repository item on value change of another repository item, subscribe to the EditValueChanged [event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItem_EditValueChangedtopic) of the latter repository item.

Any code you provide will be helpful in diagnosing the case.